# Nvidia proprietary driver on Ubuntu 16.04 causing login loop

Tags: drivers, 16.04, nvidia, graphics, login

I'm having the issue where whenever I install any proprietary nvidia driver on my Ubuntu it results in a login loop and I have to run `sudo apt purge nvidia-361`, reboot and it logs just like it should.

I'm using an Asus ROG G750JX from 2013 with an Intel i7 and a GTX 770M.

Does anyone know how to install the nvidia drivers and not result in a login loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable Secure Boot in BIOS and run

```
sudo apt install nvidia-361 nvidia-prime
```